# MYSQL statement together OR and AND

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in MySQL named sale with 3 columns like below :
sale:

```
id|customers|type
```

I want to select sales that has type!=2 OR
sales that has type=2 and customers!=0

I write statement like this :

```
sale.type != 2 OR (sale.type = 2 AND sale.customers != 0 )
```

but it doesn`t give me correct rows .

Also I have to use AND for other columns in this query but the operators between all of them is AND , just here I use OR .

Comment: what is your schema, give us a couple of rows of test data, give us what you expect to get and give us what you did get. That way it is easier to find out what you want and what went wrong...

Comment: can you create some sqlfiddle

Comment: Thanks , ((sale.type != 2) OR (sale.type = 2 AND sale.customers != 0 ) works well .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remember thus rule: bracket the OR!

```
where foo = 'bar'
and (sale.type != 2 OR (sale.type = 2 AND sale.customers != 0 ) )
and blah = 3
```

Actually your condition can be simplified to:

```
( sale.type != 2 OR sale.customers != 0 )
```

Because logically checking for sale.type = 2 is redundant.

Comment: I think `((sale.type != 2) OR ((sale.type = 2) AND (sale.customers != 0 )))` would be better

Answer (score 0):

do you want sales.type not equal to 2 or (sales.type equal to 2 when you have customers not equal to 0?)
 you can use HAVING and WHERE together.
Select * from sales where type !=2 or (type=2 HAVING customers !=0);

Answer (score 0):

Just I try with this i found working: [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/733d6/3)

```
select * from sale where
sale.type != 2 OR (sale.type = 2 AND sale.customers != 0 )
```